# How to attach a volume to a Bluemix container

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, volumes

I’m setting up a container on Bluemix using ice from the command line, but every time I try to attach a volume to a container it simply doesn’t work. The mounted folder isn't created in the root directory.

My command is:

```
ice create -p 80 -p 22 --name test --memory 1024 --volume notebooks:/notebooks registry.ng.bluemix.net/repository/app:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker gives you the option to create the volume yourself or allow Docker to create it for you. Either one of these will work:

```
docker run --name mysql_test -v /etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d jw_mysql:latest
```

OR

```
docker run --name mysql_test -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d jw_mysql:latest
```

For IBM Containers, the situation is different: you need to create a volume before you can use it. So only this will work:

```
cf ic volume create dbstorage 
cf ic run -p 3306 --name cf_mysql_test -v dbstorage:/etc/mysql/config/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d registry.ng.bluemix.net/jw_image_reg/jw_mysql:latest
```

(Assuming you want to use port 3306.)